# regexp format and using 2 cell arrays

Tags: regex, matlab, multiple-columns, cell-array

I have a matrix made of 20x cells named T.
each cell in this matrix contains the next thing:

```
1,26:00:01.490, 2.40,101.2,  7.8,-24.0,20.40,-0.76,-0.26
```

i would like to delimit and split it into columns so i used:

```
Data=regexp(T,',','split');
```

The result is that im getting Data = 20x1 cells and inside each cell theres another cell with the splited vector i wanted.

so far its all good but next thing i want to do is to take all of the time variables (`26:00:01.490` for example) but they are inside 2 cells.
The thing i wanted to do is `Data{:,1}{1,2}` but it says bad cell reference operation as an error.

someone knows how to take whole column in cell array which is inside another cell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by concatenating the data between `1x9` cells by using a combination of `vertcat` and `{:}`.

```
%//First form T
str='1,26:00:01.490, 2.40,101.2,  7.8,-24.0,20.40,-0.76,-0.26';
str=repmat({str},20,1);
Data=regexp(str,',','split');
Data1=vertcat(Data{:});

%//Get your time data in form of cells
timeData_cells=Data1(:,2);

%//Get your time data in form of a matrix
timeData_matrix=vertcat(Data1{:,2}) %//This will work only if all time strings 
                                    %//have the same length. 

%Answer
timeData_cells=
    '26:00:01.490'
    '26:00:01.490'
          .
          .
          .
    '26:00:01.490'
    '26:00:01.490'

timeData_matrix=
    26:00:01.490
    26:00:01.490
         .
         .
         .
    26:00:01.490
    26:00:01.490
```

Answer (score 2):

If all the second-level cells have the same size (that is, all your strings have the same number of commas), you can vertically concatenate all the second-level cells to form a 2D cell array, and then it's easy to access columns.

For example:

```
>> T(1,:) = {'1,26:00:01.490, 2.40,101.2, 7.8,-24.0,20.40,-0.76,-0.26'}; %// example...
>> T(2,:) = {'2,26:00:01.490, 2.40,101.2, 7.8,-24.0,20.40,-0.76,-0.26'}; %// ...with 2 rows
>> Data = regexp(T,',','split'); %// as per your code
>> Data = vertcat(Data{:}); %// concatenate vertically to obtain 2D cell array
>> Data(:,1:2) %// now you can access columns
ans = 
    '1'    '26:00:01.490'
    '2'    '26:00:01.490'
```

Comment: Hi, thank you both for the comments i just dont understand why i need to do repmat, isnt it just multiply my whole matrix?

Comment: @ben `repmat` is just a simple way I used to define an example `T` with two rows. I've edited the answer to make it clearer